# Export classifier from SCP Plugin for use in other image classification

Tags: qgis-plugins, classification, land-classification, image-classification, scp

I have run a classification using the SCP plugin in QGIS.

I want to recreate these results in a neighboring area and I am looking for help to see if it is possible to save the classification algorithm from my first raster to use in the neighboring area.

I know this is [possible with SNAP](https://forum.step.esa.int/t/classification-how-to-use-saved-classifier-on-another-product/5641) and I'm hoping there is a comprabale way to do this with SCP in QGIS.

Anyone have any expereince with this or suggestions on how to make it work?

Comment: Why you post a link from SNAP forum? I was expecting to know how to do it in ArcGIS (because I don't know how to do it there). BTW, in R this is straightforward but in others, there is no train information inside the algorithm, only vectors locating train samples. Every time process runs, collects information from train samples

Comment: Sorry, mispoke - I changed it. That link is for maximum liklihood in SNAP and there seems to be some errors in trying it. Thanks for the info about R, I'll give it a shot - I was just hoping there was a way to do it in QGIS/SCP.

Comment: You can use R scripts inside QGIS as well. SCP is a great tool, I haven't tried classification with it yet